# Looped components not showing up in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to generate `<TableHeaderColumn>`s dynamically, so that no matter what and how many columns I provide it'll render them. The component is loaded (with the searchbox and the table body) without the table headers. Anything I am doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
// Imports
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from "react-bootstrap-table";
import "../../../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/css/react-bootstrap-table.css";

// Exports
export default class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let headings;
    if (this.props.columns) {
      headings = this.props.columns.map((heading, index) => {
        let key = Object.keys(heading)[0];
        if (index === 0) {
          return <TableHeaderColumn key={heading[key]} dataField={heading[key]} isKey />
        }
        return <TableHeaderColumn key={heading[key]} dataField={heading[key]} />
      });
    }

    return (
      <BootstrapTable
        data={this.props.agentsList}
        search={this.props.options.search}
        pagination={this.props.options.pagination}
      >
        {headings}
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
}
```

And the data that is received as props is:

```
this.columns = [{ id: "ID" }, { name: "Name" }, { policies: "Policies" }];
this.options = { search: true, pagination: true };
```

I think its because of the rendering and re-rendering thing in React. Should I call `forceUpdate` or by any other means trigger a re-render of the component?

Comment: Would you put a debugger on your headings returned from the map function? Empty array return truthy value as well

Comment: @Xlee If I console.log headings, this is what I get https://jsfiddle.net/8k0mL9re/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing the column title. See [the docs](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#propsOnTableHeaderColumn).

Instead try to use

```
return <TableHeaderColumn key={heading[key]} dataField={heading[key]} isKey>{heading[key]}</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: Thank You!! That was so ignorant of me =D